# When do multiple routers connect to the same switch (ie for DR election process)

Tags: ospf

When studying for the CCNA we are presented with the 3 tier Cisco model below.

[image]

Then when we discuss routing protocols there are many images where these routers are connected in a switch and thus need a DR.
Image follows,

[image]

Or sometimes we see routers with redundant links in designs as follows .
[image]

My question is where do these interconnected routers fit in the 3-tier design?
Are they for LAN or WAN topologies?
If they are for LAN topologies did the 3 tier design go bye bye - Do most networks not follow it?
Or if it does fit into the design (as I think it may) are these interconnected topologies between the Distribution and Core routers and redundant links/routers have been kept out to simplify the design.

Its really upsetting having studied thousands of pages and not seeing one big picture where it all interconnects.

Thanks for any suggestions, help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of Cisco three-tier model are not necessarily switches.  You might well have plain layer-2 switches at the access layer, layer-3 "router" switches at the distribution layer, and a pair of switches with a pair of routers at the core.  It comes down to the performance, security, robustness and other parameters of the given network.

The routers of the distribution layer are likely to elect a router in the core layer as Designated Router (and Backup Designated Router), as they are the best connected.  This reduces the amount of traffic to distribute the routing information.

- Good explanation of the tiers: https://www.ictshore.com/free-ccna-course/three-tier-architecture/
- Good explanation of designated router: 
  https://study-ccna.com/designated-backup-designated-router/

Comment: Thanks for your time in responding.
Yes I understand the switches can be multilayer switches and the concepts behind the DR/BDR and the 3-tier design.
Was looking for a real world design that would tie those 2 subjects together.
Seems they are always separated on their own diagrams.

So per your reply we see the DR/BDR on the core.
It would be nice to see that diagram designed showing an actual switch where they all plug in, because only then will a DR be needed.
WIth  drawings of point to point mesh connections seems they are not necessary.

Comment: Re-reading your answer seems you did mention a pair of switches at the core.
Thats what I was wondering!! Thanks

Comment: Yes (per green diagram) you might have all four distribution layer units be L3 switches with a pair of connections to two core switches (for spanning tree) connected to two core routers.  The core switches might well be switch modules inside the routers.  Alternatively core routers connect to dist L3-switches by fibre.  It all depends on what's appropriate.

Comment: Nice. You'd be suprised how little info there is in that little L2/L3 domain.
Searching google for any kind of mention of OSPF in the core, or connecting multiple routers to a switch drew blanks. Thanks for the info.

Comment: PS One more thing. I assume all those routers then connect on the same subnet as well as they are on one switch, not using multiple point to point subnets in mesh.

Comment: If there are switches there, it's probably a subnet for that purpose. But it doesn't have to be ether, could easily be point-to-point fibre between the distribution layer and the core.  NB the link I gave speaks of dynamic routing eg OSPF at the core.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah reading that document it does mention fiber point links between those.
Having just completed the CCNA training it just seems so odd they spent so much time training me on the OSPF designated router on broadcast networks and I still cant find somewhere where its mandatory. Seems its more "old school" if that even?

Comment: Every multi-access network (typically ethernet) will have a DR/BDR for *that* network, to coordinate the routing information.  A given router might be DR on one interface but not another.

Comment: Yup, did many exercises on "rigging" that election via priorities etc. Wireshark captures.
Sounds like the p2p fiber links are preferred on those Distribution / Core routers.
Wondering where would that Ethernet (shared broadcast medium) connection between routers be the recommended approach. Probably for designs not following the 3 tier cisco approach perhaps?